# Pattern para notas

Tags: html, regex, entrada

buenas noches. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
pattern="[1-7]{1}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?"
```

La idea es que solo pueda colocar notas del 1 al 7 y de esta manera 4,5. Pero con ese código me admite el 7,5 por ejemplo.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo para que la máxima nota sea 7,0?

Comment: ¿A qué se deben las etiquetas html e input?

Comment: @Rubén porque `pattern`es un atributo de las etiquetas html que sirve para validad el input

Comment: Deberías agregar el HTML. Véase [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrías que agregar un o, porque no hay forma de que una vez haya pasado la validación del 7 regrese para ver si es 7 o 6.

```
([1-6](\.[0-9]{1,2})?)|7(\.00?)?
```

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que la parte decimal de tus notas es de únicamente un dígito lo puedes lograr a través de la siguiente expresión regular:

```
^([1-6](\.[0-9])?|7(\.0)?)$
```

Esta expresión matchea con números del 1 al 6 con parte decimal opcional y de un único dígito y con el valor "7" o "7.0"

`[1-6]` : numero del 1 al 6

`(\.[0-9])?` grupo opcional, un "`.`" seguido de un *único* número del 0-9

`7(\.0)?` el valor "7" o "7.0"

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/LTipi6mf3o9Ul71B)